# How many homes can you get in the Happy Home Showcase in Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I'm wondering if you can get as many houses with StreetPass as you want, but is it possible? I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You are limited to having a maximum of 48 houses in the Happy Home Showcase at any one time.

If you collect more, they will replace the oldest houses, unless those houses have been saved by marking them with a heart (however, you are limited to saving a maximum of 16 houses.)